# How can I treat an array of values to be a tuple that is inferred based on what's passed to it

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React component like this:

```
interface Props<T> {
  data: {
    items: T[]
  }[]
}


const MyComponent = <T,>(props: Props<T>) => {
  return ...
}


<MyComponent data={[
  {
    items: [{ name: 'A', age: 10 }, { name: 'B', age: 20 }]
  },
  {
    items: [{ label: 'A', value: 25 }, { label: 'C', value: 50 }
  }
]} />
```

In this example, I want the first `data` item to have `T = {name: string, age: number}` and the second `data` item to have `T = { label: string, value: number }`

I know that this is possible with tuples but I want to infer the tuple from the props that are passed to it.

Comment: Not really sure I understand. Each item in data can have any data type in `item` but for one element they must be the same ? Or ? It's not really clear. What values wouldn't be ok for `data` ?

Comment: When I set data like above, the type for `T` generic type is `{ name?: string, age?: number, label?: string, value?: number }`. I want to make it so that T becomes a tuple: `[{ name: string, age: number}, { label: string, value: number }]`

Comment: Here is an example (hover over `data`):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOAeAFQD5kBvAWAChlkATOMOALjKppuEgFscWCBtALptkAXyFVRVaZQQYQOMMgCyATwDCGLlnkRwyALzJCAGiIAKLJlwt02fMQCUhkhWrIoEMAFcoIZCDeADZBANySMgD0kcgEAMpoQXCqAOaY3iC0yHLaSaA4yADuABZ6yACSyN44KABKEIhKOTogemBUaprauuDmbjT0jCz8-eycEDzDpAFwXBAsAOQAggsmyHAp88gAjAAMYmvTILNbCwBCq+ubLABM+6LC7qImIqMc3LzII8hJAEYQQUWKzWADc4EFvFsbgBWA5kH5wf6A5ALdSXMEQrbQ+6PGjPESPUSOGRAA

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
interface Props<T1, T2> {
  data: [{ items: T1[] }, { items: T2[] }]
}

const MyComponent = <T1,T2>(props: Props<T1, T2>) => {
  return null;
}
```

Which could be further optimized if needed.